# When testing a regular expression, result is not returning false as intended for maximum string length

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am currently working on a program that uses regular expressions.  This is the section I'm referring to:

`var require = /^[A-Z]{1,2}[A-Z0-9]$/;`

```
var result = require.test(given_init);
```

Where `given_init` is a set of initials inputted by the user.  My problem is that I want the program to return a false value from the second line when more than 2 characters are entered into `given_init` , thus setting the max length to 2.

I'm attempting to do this by setting a range at `{1,2}` , as seen above.  However, if I input ABC, the .test method is still not returning false.  I'm assuming this is because I am using regular expressions incorrectly, so if anyone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Examples:
Input: ABC
Expected Output: False

Input: AB
Expected Output: True

Comment: The regular expression in your question matches one or two capital letters, followed by either a capital letter or a number.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the correct expression should be

```
var require = /^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]$/;
```

because you need EXACTLY 2 character occurrences.
The first is only capital letters, thus `[A-Z]` and the second is capital letters or numbers thus `[A-Z0-9]`

There is no need for the `{1,2}` because this way you express that you need one or two characters between A-Z AND one more character in the range A-Z or 0-9

Comment: I tried the following: `var require = /^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]$/;` but unfortunately it was still returned as true.  Not sure if I'm entering it wrong.

Comment: This is what I get: `var require = /^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]$/;` 
`require.test("ABC")` => false, `require.test("AB")` => true. Do you expect something different ?

Comment: The above is what I'm expecting.  Upon messing with the expression more and adding dummy requirements to trigger a false return no matter what I input, it seems that my main problem is that false won't trigger no matter what requirements are set to.  If anyone has any guidance for why this would be, please let me know.  If not I appreciate the help for my original problem.

Comment: @SpecialDev - In my browser console I typed/executed these three statements which demonstrate that antoniom's regex is working correctly... `var require = /^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]$/;`⮐ `var tests = [ 'AB', 'ABC', 'A9', 'A9Z' ];`⮐ `tests.forEach(t => console.log(\`test: "${t}" : ${require.test(t)}\`));`⮐

Comment: @SpecialDev please provide some sample input and expected output so that we can guide you through. Eg. 'AB' should return true, 'ABC' should return false, 'A1' should return true etc.